# Get Geolocation Bing Map W10 Universal App When Right Clicked/Long Press

Tags: c#, xaml, bing-maps, win-universal-app

I'm developing a universal map for windows 10 (VS 2015) and I have a map control. I want to capture a long press / right click event and determine the geolocation (lat/lng) where the user presses. I've tried capturing the right click event, but it never fires whether I use the mouse or a long press on the map:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Maps:MapControl
            x:Name="Map"
            MapServiceToken="<MY_TOKEN>"
            ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
            LandmarksVisible="True"
            IsRightTapEnabled="true"
            RightTapped="Map_RightTapped"
            />

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C#:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Map_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Here");
        }
    }
}
```

Evidently I'm missing something. Thanx,

Update: I have a work around of sorts. I can capture the data I need from a long press using the MapHolding event, but there does not seem to be support for a right click. The class documentation indicates there is a MapRightTapped event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.maprighttapped.aspx) but it isn't available either in in the XAML editor or in the .cs file using intellisense. Note that the event is MapHolding, not Holding (e.g., use myMap.MapHolding += EventHandlerMethod, **not** myMap.Holding += EventHandlerMethod).

Comment: The control might be marking the event as handled and is swallowing it. Have you tried registering for handled events as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185584.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler.aspx) ?

Comment: Yah, I tried that to no avail. Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right click event is not currently supported on the map however,  this is in the next Windows update later this month.

Comment: Is there any source/reference of what API changes will come with the update?

Comment: That is consistent with the behavior. I have a work around for now that uses a button click event rather than a map right tapped event. I'll keep an eye on this and hopefully the forthcoming update will resolve this issue. If so, I'll add the particulars to this thread. Thanx,